# Understand input shape to LSTM network

Tags: tensorflow, keras, lstm

I have a data of the shape : (753,8,1)
this is the LSTM model built for the data:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(32,input_shape=(8,1)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error' , optimizer='adam' , metrics=['accuracy'] )
```

But on training it on data: 
`epochs_hist = model.fit(reshaped_segments , labels ,  batch_size=20 , epochs=5 , validation_split=0.2)`

I am getting the following error:
ValueError: Error when checking model target: the list of Numpy arrays that you are passing to your model is not the size the model expected. Expected to see 1 array(s), but instead got the following list of 753 arrays: [array([[0]]), array([[0]]), array([[0]]), array([[0]]), array([[1]]), array([[0]]), array([[0]]), array([[0]]), array([[1]]), array([[1]]), array([[0]]), array([[1]]), array([[1]]), array([[0]]), arr...

Comment: The error is about the target, not about the input.

Answer (score 0):

try to flatten your label in this way:

```
labels = np.concatenate(labels).ravel()
```

at the end labels.shape must be (753,)